# Imprimir palabras aleatorias en el juego de ahorcado

Tags: c

Estaba modificando un videojuego del ahorcado y me quedé corto en un parte que me pareció que me resultaría fácil. Quería que en vez que el usuario escribiera la palabra a adivinar, el programa tomara de una lista de palabras una al azar para jugar. Pero empecé a tener problemas con el char, los caracteres, valores, etc.

Se como generar palabras al azar de una lista, pero este me resultó muy diferente pues estas palabras las tengo que utilizar para el juego. (Vean el programa para que entiendan). Solo tengo duda en esa parte, si alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo se le agradeceré mucho.

Publico el programa original,(No hace falta leerlo todo) para no confundirlos con el que tengo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char frase[60],rep[100],temporal[100];
    char pal;
    int longitud,i,j,inicial,acertado=0,temp=0,oportunidades=5;
    int repetido=0,gano=0;

    printf("\tJuego del Ahorcado\n");
    printf("Introduzca la palabra a adivinar: ");
    gets(frase);

    system("cls");

    longitud = 0;
    inicial = 0;
    j = 0;

    rep[0] = ' ';
    rep[1] = '\0';


    do {
                system("cls");
        temp=0;

        if(inicial == 0) {
         for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++) {
          if(frase[i] == ' ') {
            temporal[i] = ' ';
             longitud++;
          }
          else {
             temporal[i] = '_';       
             longitud++;
          }
         }
        }

        inicial = 1;

        temporal[longitud] = '\0';

        for(i=0;i<strlen(rep);i++) {
           if(rep[i] == pal) {
            repetido = 1;
            break;
          }
          else {
           repetido = 0;
         }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {
         for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++) {
                    if(frase[i] == pal) {
             temporal[i] = pal;
              acertado++;
              temp=1;
            }
          }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {
         if(temp == 0) {
           oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
         }
        }
        else {
         printf("Ya se ha introducido este caracter");
         printf("\n\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(i=0;i<strlen(temporal);i++) {
         printf(" %c ",temporal[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        if(strcmp(frase,temporal) == 0) {
            gano = 1;
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Letras Acertadas: %d",acertado);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Oportunidades Restantes: %d",oportunidades);
        printf("\n");

        rep[j] = pal;
        j++;

        if (oportunidades==0)
        {
           break;
        }

        printf("Introduzca una letra:");
        scanf("\n%c",&pal);

    }while(oportunidades != 0);


    if(gano) {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enhorabuena, has ganado.");
    }
    else {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Has perdido.");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Escoger una palabra al azar de una lista es lo mismo, la utilices para que la utilices. Si es para imprimirla, la pasas a un *printf*. Si es para otra cosa, pues lo que se necesite (por ejemplo meterla en una variable para después usarla a cada letra que introduzca el usuario).

Comment: Y yo **ni siquiera veo la pregunta** por ningún lado O_O

Comment: Es porque, era el programa original a modificar, este tenia solo tenia que introducir la palabra pero el mio era que el usuario tendria que adivinar, y pues no lo puse porque pense que seria mejor empezar desde cero.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi que quieres tener ya palabras definidas, lo que puedes hacer es tener un array de strings, colocadas en un puntero, para después con la libreria de time seleccione una palabra aleatoria del mismo array y sería todo lo que tenfas que modificar.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Incluimos una libreria para que se seleccione aleatoriamente
#include<time.h>

char *cadena[] = {"Palabra1", "Palabra2", "Palabra3", "Palabra4", "Palabra5"};

int main() {
    char frase[60],rep[100],temporal[100];
    char pal;
    int longitud,i,j,inicial,acertado=0,temp=0,oportunidades=5;
    int repetido=0,gano=0;

    printf("\tJuego del Ahorcado\n");
    //Luego inicializar los números aleatorios incluyendo esto:
    srand(time(NULL));

    //Luego guardar el número aleatorio en alguna parte:
    int num = rand();
    //Número aleatorio
    num=rand()%5;
    //Sólo para mostrar la palabra
    printf("%s\n", cadena[num]);
    //printf("Introduzca la palabra a adivinar: ");
    //gets(frase);

    system("cls");

    longitud = 0;
    inicial = 0;
    j = 0;

    rep[0] = ' ';
    rep[1] = '\0';


    do {
                system("cls");
        temp=0;

        if(inicial == 0) {
         for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena[num]);i++) {
          if(cadena[num][i] == ' ') {
            temporal[i] = ' ';
             longitud++;
          }
          else {
             temporal[i] = '_';       
             longitud++;
          }
         }
        }

        inicial = 1;

        temporal[longitud] = '\0';

        for(i=0;i<strlen(rep);i++) {
           if(rep[i] == pal) {
            repetido = 1;
            break;
          }
          else {
           repetido = 0;
         }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {
         for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena[num]);i++) {
                    if(cadena[num][i] == pal) {
             temporal[i] = pal;
              acertado++;
              temp=1;
            }
          }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {
         if(temp == 0) {
           oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
         }
        }
        else {
         printf("Ya se ha introducido este caracter");
         printf("\n\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(i=0;i<strlen(temporal);i++) {
         printf(" %c ",temporal[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        if(strcmp(cadena[num],temporal) == 0) {
            gano = 1;
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Letras Acertadas: %d",acertado);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Oportunidades Restantes: %d",oportunidades);
        printf("\n");

        rep[j] = pal;
        j++;

        if (oportunidades==0)
        {
           break;
        }

        printf("Introduzca una letra:");
        scanf("\n%c",&pal);

    }while(oportunidades != 0);


    if(gano) {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enhorabuena, has ganado.");
    }
    else {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Has perdido.");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```